# PostgreSQL: regex replace first level square brackets with curly braces

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have data in a PostgreSQL column of type TEXT that I need to do some character replacement on.  Specifically I want to replace square brackets with curly braces.  The catch is that I only want to replace the brackets that are no more than two levels deep, if you include the main enclosing brackets.  These strings can be quite long so I think a regex is probably the way to go (`regexp_replace` function) but I'm no good with regex expressions.  Here's an example of one such value:

```
[0,0,0,[12,2],0,0,[12,[1,2,3]],12,0,[12,2,[2]],12,0,12,0,0]
```

So I would want this string to change to:

```
{0,0,0,{12,2},0,0,{12,[1,2,3]},12,0,{12,2,[2]},12,0,12,0,0}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed solutions.  I'll need a little time to evaluate these.  I will mention, however, that performance is a big consideration.  I had already created my own plpgsql solution but using position() and substr() is way too slow on columns that can contain over 10 million characters, as is the case for me.  Sorry I didn't mention that in my initial post, @wildplasser.

Comment: I'll further mention that I had started on a plpythonu solution but that language extension is not currently installed and I get an error trying to install it.  I may have to bite the bullet and figure that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be a pain with Regex as [in PostgreSQL flavor possibly no recursion is available](http://www.regular-expressions.info/postgresql.html).

For a **maximum of 2 levels nested depth** check, if the following double replace works (can't test it)

```
regexp_replace(
  regexp_replace('str', E'\\[(([^][]|\\[([^][]|\\[[^][]*\\])*\\])*)\\]', E'{\\1}', 'g')
, E'\\[(([^][]|\\[([^][]|\\[[^][]*\\])*\\])*)\\]', E'{\\1}', 'g')
```

The idea is to match and replace the outermost `[]` in two passes.
See example at regex101:

[pass 1](http://regex101.com/r/kA8qC3/1): `{0,0,0,[12,2],0,0,[12,[1,2,3]],12,0,[12,2,[2]],12,0,12,0,0}`
[pass 2](http://regex101.com/r/kA8qC3/2): `{0,0,0,{12,2},0,0,{12,[1,2,3]},12,0,{12,2,[2]},12,0,12,0,0}`

`\[[^][]*\]` (unescaped) matches an instance of `[...]`

- `\[` opening square bracket
- `[^][]*` followed by any amount of characters, that are no square brackets
- `\]` followed by a closing square bracket

Note, that if the string always starts with `[`, ends with `]` and represents one instance of level 0 (without being delimited by `][`) the first/inner `regexp_replace` can also be done by replacing `[` at `^` start and `]` at the `$` end: `E'^\\[(.*)\\]$'` with `E'{\\1}'`

---

To add nesting here an example with max 4 levels of depth:

```
\[([^][]|    # outer
\[([^][]|    # lvl 1
\[([^][]|    # lvl 2
\[([^][]|    # lvl 3
\[[^][]*\]   # lvl 4
)*\]
)*\]
)*\]
)*\]
```

Wrapping what's inside the outer `[]` into a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) the pattern for 4 levels would become:

```
\[(([^][]|\[([^][]|\[([^][]|\[([^][]|\[[^][]*\])*\])*\])*\])*)\]
```

For use with `regex_replace` need probably additional escaping of `[]`

```
\\[(([^][]|\\[([^][]|\\[([^][]|\\[([^][]|\\[[^][]*\\])*\\])*\\])*\\])*)\\]
```

This can be used like the first pattern in two passes and replaced with `E'{\\1}'`

Comment: Jonny 5, this works!  The other solutions offered also look promising, but this successfully employs regex as I had more or less asked for.  Also as I indicated in my later comments, I had already tried @wildplasser's approach and it's just too slow on really long text values.  On a string of a few hundred thousand characters the position and substring approach would never finish after hours of processing.  This regex approach takes 270 ms as reported by pgAdmin!  I also really appreciate the detailed explanation of the regex and how to do deeper if necessary.  Well done!

Comment: @PaulAngelno Well, if speed is a concern I suggest using PL/Python, which is quite a bit faster, or using a C extension like the example I posted. I don't think regular expressions are the right tool for this job, though that's what you asked for.

Comment: @CraigRinger, agreed and I was interested to work with this in plpythonu and see how it performed, especially since the data is already in Python list format.  Unfortunately the Python extension isn't working in my environment and searching on that issue suggests I would have to rebuild my PostgreSQL from source, etc.  For now I'll take the path of last resistance.

Comment: Paul, happy that works for you as I could not test it :) and plus @CraigRinger for providing different views on the problem and doing all the benchmarking.

Answer (score 3):

This is ugly, but it works (and avoids the regexp-complexity ;-) I hope I have all the corner cases covered...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replbracket( _source text ) returns text
AS $func$
DECLARE
        pos_end INTEGER;
        pos_begin INTEGER;
        level INTEGER;
        result text;
BEGIN
        result = '' ;
        level = 0;
LOOP
        pos_begin = position ( '[' IN _source );
        pos_end = position ( ']' IN _source );
        -- raise notice 'Source=% Result=% Begin = % End=%'
                -- ,_source, result, pos_begin, pos_end;

        if (pos_begin < 1 AND pos_end < 1) THEN EXIT ;
        elsif (pos_begin < 1 ) THEN pos_begin =  pos_end + 1 ;
        elsif (pos_end < 1 ) THEN pos_end =  pos_begin + 1 ;
        end if;
        if (pos_begin < pos_end) THEN
                result = result || LEFT(_source, pos_begin-1);
                level = level + 1;
                if (level <= 2) THEN result = result || '{'; else result = result || '['; end if;
                _source = SUBSTR(_source, pos_begin+1);
        ELSE
                result = result || LEFT(_source, pos_end-1);
                level  = level - 1;
                if (level < 2) THEN result = result || '}'; else result = result || ']'; end if;
                _source = SUBSTR(_source, pos_end+1);
        END IF;
END LOOP;
        result = result || _source ;
        return result;
END

$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for kicks, here's a solution entirely in SQL. It uses CTEs for notational clarity, but you could use subqueries in FROM instead, there's no recursive CTE use.

**Edit**: Added simplified, faster SQL version, version in Pl/Python, and version in C. The C one is a tad faster - about 250 times faster.

```
create or replace function repl(text) 
returns text 
language sql
as $$
with 
chars(pos, ch) as (
    -- In PostgreSQL 9.4 this can be replaced with an UNNEST ... WITH ORDINALITY
    -- it turns the string into a list of chars accompanied by their position within
    -- the string.
    select row_number() OVER (), ch
    from regexp_split_to_table($1,'') ch
),
nesting(ch, pos, lvl) as (
    -- This query then determines how many levels of nesting of [s and ]s are
    -- in effect for each character.
    select ch, pos, 
        sum(case ch when '[' then 1 when ']' then -1 else 0 end) OVER (ORDER BY pos) 
        from chars
),
transformed(ch, pos) as (
    -- and this query transforms [s to {s or ]s to }s if the nesting
    -- level is appropriate. Note that we use one less level of nesting
    -- for closing brackets because the closing bracket it self has already
    -- reduced the nesting level.
    select 
      case
        when ch = '[' and lvl <= 2 then '{' 
        when ch = ']' and lvl <= 1 then '}' 
        else ch
      end,
      pos
    from nesting
)
-- Finally, reconstruct the new string from the (char, position) tuples
select 
  string_agg(ch, '' order by pos)
from transformed;
$$;
```

However, it's slower than the other solutions.

- Johnny 5's regexp solution takes 450ms for 10,000 iterations.
- wildplasser's `replbracket` takes 950ms for 10,000 iterations.
- This CTE solution takes 2050ms for 10,000 iterations.

Getting rid of the CTEs and using `unnest ... with ordinality` speeds it up to about 1400ms:

```
create or replace function repl(text) returns text language sql volatile as
$$
    select
      string_agg(ch, '' order by pos)
    from (
        select
          case
            when ch = '[' and sum(case ch when '[' then 1 when ']' then -1 else 0 end) OVER (ORDER BY pos) <= 2 then '{'
            when ch = ']' and sum(case ch when '[' then 1 when ']' then -1 else 0 end) OVER (ORDER BY pos) <= 1 then '}'
            else ch
          end,
          pos
        from unnest(regexp_split_to_array($1,'')) with ordinality as chars(ch, pos)
    ) as transformed(ch, pos)
$$;
```

If you want fast, use a proper procedural language - or C. In PL/Python2:

```
create or replace function replpy(instr text) returns text language plpythonu as $$
def pyrepl(instr):
    level=0
    for ch in instr:
        if ch == '[':
                level += 1
                if level <= 2:
                        yield '{'
                else:
                        yield '['
        elif ch == ']':
                if level <= 2:
                        yield '}'
                else:
                        yield ']'
                level -= 1
        else:
                yield ch

return ''.join(pyrepl(instr))
$$;
```

it takes 160ms.

OK, flogging a dead horse, lets do it in C. [Full source code as an extension is here](https://github.com/ringerc/scrapcode/tree/master/postgresql/string_transform) but here's the .c file:

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "utils/builtins.h"

PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(replc);
Datum replc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);

PGDLLEXPORT Datum
replc(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    /* Set `buf` to a palloc'd copy of the input string, deTOASTed if needed */
    char * const buf = text_to_cstring(PG_GETARG_TEXT_PP(0));
    char * ch = buf;
    int depth = 0;


    while (*ch != '\0')
    {
        switch (*ch)
        {
            case '[':
                depth++;
                if (depth <= 2)
                    *ch = '{';
                break;
            case ']':
                if (depth <= 2)
                    *ch = '}';
                depth--;
                break;
        }
        ch++;
    }
    if (depth != 0)
        ereport(WARNING,
                (errmsg("Opening and closing []s did not match, got %d extra [s", depth)));

    PG_RETURN_DATUM(CStringGetTextDatum(buf));
}
```

Runtime: 8ms for 10,000 iterations. Good enough, it's 250 times faster than the original, and that's with the overhead of a forced subquery.